# Aligning content within a table with CSS

Tags: css, html-table, alignment

I have a table in my HTML that is defined like the following

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='corner1.png' /></td>
    <td>First Name <a href='#'>edit</a></td>
    <td><img src='corner2.png' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the `edit` link to be right-aligned within the cell. But I want "First Name" to be left-aligned. Currently, everything is left-aligned. How can I make the link right-aligned?

Comment: since you're already using a table, why don't you put 'First Name' and 'edit' in separate `td`s

Answer (score 1):

`<td><a href='#' class="floatRight">edit</a> First Name</td>`

Entry in CSS file `.floatRight {float:right;}`

Moved `edit` before First Name else some browsers will show it in new line and not in-line with First Name.

Answer (score 0):

Set a float on the `<a>` element:

```
table tr td a {
    float: right
}
```

This will push the `<a>` to the right of the cell. The selector is a bit too specific - at minimum it could be `table a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following CSS:

```
td a {
    float: right;
}
```